# % char in computer name in Mac Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

When I open the Mac terminal I see:

```
username@ComputerName ~ %
```

Those last two chars are not included in my computer name.

why is the terminal rendering them ?
how can I wipe them out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` is your current working directory.
`%` is a character to prompt your input after it.

You could inspect this configuration by `echo $PS1`, and change the value of `PS1` is how you modify those characters.

A source to refer: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization

Answer (score 0):

I was using zsh.

you can change this is the Terminal preferences, selecting bin/bash s default